# How to set value for a OneToOne relationship?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have 2 models which is defined as one to one.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Form_Item_Production")
public class FormItemProduction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private Long itemId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shift_lookup_id")
    private AppLookup appLookup;

    getter and setter
}
```

the other one is a lookup table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "App_Lookup")
public class AppLookup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Lookup_Id", nullable = false)
    private Long lookupId;

    @Column(name = "Lookup_Name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String lookupName;

    getter and setter
}
```

I tried adding values to the "shift_lookup_id" in my DB to a sysout print and the relationship between the 2 tables work as I was able to print out the correct value

```
for (FormItemProduction x : a) {
    System.out.println("YEAH RIGHT " + x.getAppLookup().getLookupName());
}
```

Since I only manually added the value in the DB, I am now trying to save the value from my jsp file but not exactly know what to write in the input:

```
 <form:input path="formItemProduction.shiftLookupId" />
```

Doing this wont save the value form jsp to the model I binded. I tried to add an extra field in my entity

```
@Column(name = "shift_lookup_id", nullable = true)
private String shiftLookupId;
```

But its throwing an error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.mamee.factory.security.entity.FormItemProduction column: shift_lookup_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Any idea how to how to properly write the path in the form:input or do I need to change my model?

Answer (score 0):

Fix by using this:

```
<form:input path="formItemProduction.appLookup.lookupId" />
```

Able store the value from jsp and pass to my controller model